# IBM Mobilefirst platform - Access denied when trying to connect to HTTP Adapter

Tags: android, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I have a native android app which is supposed to communicate with an HTTP Adapter. However when i try to connect to the adapter i get the following response - "Access Denied 
Reason: Failed due to missing ChallengeHandler for realm - {1}"

The error is pretty self-explanatory. But i have not enabled any authentication on the adapter. Hence I am not sure why i am getting this error. Anyways is there any way to disable the authentication? I am a beginner and i simply want a end-to-end communication between the app and the adapter.

Comment: Attempt to add securityTest="wl_unprotected" to your procedure definition in the adapter XML file.

Comment: @IdanAdar: Actually i was using securityTest="wl_unprotected" for some of the procedures of the adapter. But not for all procedures. Now by adding the same for all procedures has solved the issue. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

> Attempt to add securityTest="wl_unprotected" to your procedure definition in the adapter XML file.